# Dissolving photoconductor (TiOPc) from Laser Printer drum possible?

Tags: optics, electrostatics, laser, photoelectric-effect, microscopy

When I was thinking of a Lab-On-a Chip Application which combines a lensless microscope and an optical tweezers I saw the ODEP-concept:(http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2013/lc/c3lc50351h#!divAbstract). 
This works like a laser printer. The probe is sandwiched between two transparaent conducting surfaces (e.g. ITO idium tin oxide), where one of the layers has a photoconductive substance on it.

When putting an osciallating voltage (eg. +/-20V at 1Mhz) to the two electrodes one can switch on/off the charges on the surfaces. The result is an electric field gradient which is capable of manipulating particles or biological cells.

I was thinking to use "standard" materials from old laser printers. The blue printer drum has several layers as seen [here](http://www.hodogaya.co.jp/english/products/imaging_materials/). The newer ones use TiOPc which fits perfectly to the "lab-on-a-chip" application.

Does any think it's possible to get the TiOPc or the entire layer apart from the alluminium drum to put it back on an ito-coated glass substrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the TiOPc on printer drums may be TiOPc nanoparticles embedded in some kind of organic binder, rather than solid TiOPc.

See this: http://patents.justia.com/patent/20140054510 for example for the challenges of dissolving TiOPc in *anything*.

The binder on the other hand should be easy to dissolve; try acetone first, if that doesn't work, perhaps brake cleaner or paint stripper (in a fume hood! you don't want to inhale it).